# FlexUnit4 in IntelliJ

Tags: apache-flex, intellij-idea, flexunit, flexunit4

When I try to run test with FlexUnit4 and IntelliJ, I get this error:

```
SecurityError: Error #2148: SWF file file:///C|/Users/LIC/Projects/ProgramJef/out/production/Flex%2DClient%2DTests/%5Fflexunit.swf cannot access local resource file:///C|/Users/LIC/Projects/ProgramJef/out/production/Flex%2DClient%2DTests/textLayout_1.1.0.604.swf. Only local-with-filesystem and trusted local SWF files may access local resources.
    at flash.net::URLStream/load()
    at flash.net::URLLoader/load()
    at mx.core::CrossDomainRSLItem/load()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\CrossDomainRSLItem.as:240]
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/loadNext()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:184]
    at mx.core::RSLListLoader/load()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\RSLListLoader.as:156]
    at mx.preloaders::Preloader/initialize()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:279]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::initialize()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:1925]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/initHandler()[E:\dev\4.x\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2419]
```

I really wouldn't know what the problem is here, and I can't find anything on it online. Even on IntelliJ and FlexUnit4 there's not much to find...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must allow the resulting SWF access to your file system. Set the Flashplayer trust settings in a file. On Linux this file must be in

```
~/.macromedia/Flash_Player/#Security/FlashPlayerTrust/
```

(for Windows there is a similar path somewhere) and create a file that lists the output path of your project, e.g.

```
/dev/myproject/target
/dev/anotherproject/target
```

In case 'target' is our output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set up your test sources folder right? In Project Settings under Modules, add Flex and click Flex and add Text Source Folders using the tree structure on the right hand side.

(IntelliJ 9.0.2)